# Bash: How to change system-wide proxy settings

Tags: linux, ssh, socks5-proxy

I want all my client-traffic to go over an SSH-Tunnel. Therefor I set the System-Proxy to "**socks5://127.0.0.1:1080**" after connecting to the server using SSH:

```
ssh -D 1080 john@myserver.com
```

I need to switch the Network-Proxy-Setting's Method-dropdown from "None" to "Manual" everytime because when having it enabled per default, I cannot establish the SSH-Connection on login via the .bashrc.

I tried using "http(s)_proxy"-variable and export it but this does only work for shells, not the entire system. Yes I could change proxy-settings for each application like, FTP-Client, Browser, .. but this would cut my flexibility a lot.

**Q:** Whats the equivalent bash-command to change the system-wide network-proxy-settings like I would do over the UI? I could keep the proxy-information static and just change the Method from "None" to "Manual" as it works via the UI.

*I am using Fedora 24.*

[image: Manual Proxy Settings]

Comment: Use `gsettings` as shown in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152292/70524

Comment: **gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode manual** did the trick! That simple. Thank you sir!